# How to make org-mode refiled items visible in the logbook agenda view

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In my `.emacs` file, I have the variable setting `'(org-log-refile (quote time))`. This means that when I refile something with `C-c C-w`, an inactive timestamp is added, for example:

```
* TODO a task 

    - Refiled on [2013-10-13 Sun 15:17]
```

When I am in an org-mode calendar agenda view, hitting `l` (that's a lower-case L, not a 1)  triggers `org-agenda-log-mode`. This means that I see clocked items added to my agenda. However, I do not see refiled items, which is not what I would expect. For what it may be worth, I already have the following variable setting in my `.emacs` file as well: `'(org-agenda-log-mode-items (quote (closed clock state)))`

So, how do I get refiled items to appear on my agenda when in `org-agenda-log-mode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps` to `'t`

Either by `(setq org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps 't)` or by adding it ot your `org-agenda-custom-commands` as one of the options, e.g.:

```lisp
(agenda ""
        ((org-agenda-span 'day)
         (org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps 't)))
```

Adding this as part of `org-agenda-custom-commands` makes the variable `let-bound`.  It will only apply to the current agenda and not set as a default.  If you want it set as a default for all agenda commands you can use the following:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps 't)
```

Comment: That's helpful to know... So to get the behavior I want, the question then seems to be how I would modify the function `org-agenda-log-mode` in `org-agenda.el` so that whenever it toggles `org-agenda-show-log` it will also toggle `org-agenda-include-inactive-timestamps` to have the same value. I just don't understand elisp enough to make sense of `org-agenda-log-mode`.

Comment: Are you currently using a custom agenda command? `org-agenda-custom-commands` or are you using one of the built in commands?

Comment: After thinking about it, I'm not sure you can safely set it to toggle with `org-agenda-log-mode`.  You can toggle it on and off with log-mode, however if you open a new agenda view it will keep whatever the current value was (So if it was showing and you change views, it will keep showing even if log-mode is off)

Comment: I normally use a single agenda view all the time, which is set in `org-agenda-custom-commands`. It starts without log-mode turned on, which is normally what I want, and I also will not normally want to see inactive timestamps. I could build another custom view like the one you suggest in your original answer, but then won't inactive timestamps stay turned on for the other views, unless the other views explicitly reset it to `nil`?

Comment: Variables that are set as part of `org-agenda-custom-commands` like my example in the answer are `let-bound` so they only apply to the current agenda view.